# How to chunk an array based on another array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of data, and an array of objects:

```
const data = ['1', '2', '2'];
const objlist = [{name : 'dummy'} , {name: 'new'}, {name : 'news'}, {name : 'place'}, ...]; // 5 objects
```

I want to chunk the objects in `objlist` by the numbers in `data` so that I get the follow result:

```
result = [
  [{name:'dummy'}], 
  [{name:'new'}, {name:'news'}],
  [{name : 'place'}, ...]
]
```

As you can see, it should be of the form:

```js
[[{obj1}], [{obj2}, {obj3}], [{obj4}, {obj5}]]
```

Comment: You have the expected output, but please put in words what you are trying to do

Comment: what is the meaning of the numbers of `array`? do you want to slice the array in parts?

Comment: i have updated the question with detail , Yes i want to it be sliced @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could push sliced parts to the result.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 2],
    objlist = [{ name: 'dummy' }, { name: 'new' }, { name: 'news' }, { name: 'place' }, { name: 'place' }],
    result = [],
    i = 0,
    j = 0;
    
while (j < array.length) {
    result.push(objlist.slice(i, i += array[j++]));
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array of numbers and for each number `n` use `.splice(0, n)` to get an array chunk from your array of objects. This will modify the array in-place, allowing your next [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to get the next consecutive object. For each `.splice()` you perform, you can [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) this into a resulting array.

See example below:

```js
function partition([...arr], chunks) {
  const res = [];
  for(const n of chunks)
    res.push(arr.splice(0, n)); // +n to turn the string number into a number (splice will do this conversion for you but you can take care of it explicitly as well)
  return res;
}

const chunkArr = ['1', '2', '2'];
const arr = [{ name : 'dummy' }, {name: 'new' }, { name : 'news'},{name : 'place'}, {name : 'foo'}];

console.log(partition(arr, chunkArr));
```

Above I'm using `partition([...arr], chunks)` which uses the [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to perform a shallow copy of your input array. This way when you modify it inside your function using `.splice()`, it won't change the passed-in array.