# Split array ["banana", "apple", "orange", .....etc ] into groups based on other array, ie. [2,7,3]

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, slice

I have a bunch arrays, that I need to split into smaller groups based off the numbers in another matching array. Example:

```
var myArray1 = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "pear", "pineapple", "grapes", "apricot", "plum"];
var splitArray1 = [3,2,2,1];
```

I want a function to return 4 sub arrays:

```
[["banana", "apple", "orange"], ["pear", "pineapple"], ["grapes", "apricot"], ["plum"]];
```

I have found this code which is apparently meant to do just this, but it returns the full array:

```
function chunkArray(array, size) {
    var chunked_arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var last = chunked_arr[chunked_arr.length - 1];
      if (!last || last.length === size) {
        chunked_arr.push([array[i]]);
      } else {
        last.push(array[i]);
      }
    }
    return chunked_arr;
}
```

This is in google apps script if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Terry Am I missing something, but dosn't both the answers at the given [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63706698/compare-a-array-and-an-object-array-and-push-the-contents-into-the-new-array-acc) answer this?

Comment: *"To someone unfamiliar with 'mutating' an array ..."* mutation is when you change some property of an object; like adding/removing/sorting elements from an array. The "issue" with mutation is that as modern applications are larger and more distributed it gets hard for humans to grasp all the implications of a mutation. Some unrelated part of your app may also hold a reference to this object and your changes here may introduce unexpected behaviour/bugs over there just due to the sheer coincidence that they both and use the very same object. Check out immutability; concept and implementations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var myArray1 = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "pear", "pineapple", "grapes", "apricot", "plum"];
var splitArray1 = [3,2,2,1];

const output = splitArray1.map(count => myArray1.splice(0, count));
console.log(output)
```

---

Above solution updates the original `myArray1` array. Here is another solution using [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var myArray1 = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "pear", "pineapple", "grapes", "apricot", "plum"];
var splitArray1 = [3,2,2,1];
var startCount = 0;

const output = splitArray1.map(count => myArray1.slice(startCount, startCount += count));
console.log(output)
```

Comment: `const output = splitArray1.map(count => myArray1.splice(0, count));`

Comment: no need for mutating the original array.

Comment: I have added a new solution using Array.slice() with no mutating.

Comment: :) in your second snippet, you can inline `startCount += count` and also shorten it to `const output = splitArray1.map(count => myArray1.slice(startCount, startCount += count));` although some people may have an issue with this regarding readability; that the assignment in `+=` may be easy to overlook.